# I get error "Error in nnet.default(x, y, w, ...) : too many (77031) weights" while training neural networks

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, nnet

I am trying to train neural networks in R using package `nnet`. Following is the information about my training data.

```
str(traindata)

'data.frame':   10327 obs. of  196 variables:
$ stars                          : num  5 5 5 3.5 3.5 4.5 3.5 5 5 3.5 ...
$ open                           : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ city                           : Factor w/ 61 levels "ahwatukee","anthem",..: 36 38
$ review_count                   : int  3 5 4 5 14 6 21 4 14 10 ...
$ name                           : Factor w/ 8204 levels " leftys barber shop",..:
$ longitude                      : num  -112 -112 -112 -112 -112 ...
$ latitude                       : num  33.6 33.6 33.5 33.4 33.7 ...
$ greek                          : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ breakfast...brunch             : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ soup                           : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

I have truncated this information.

When I run the following:

```
library(nnet)  
m4 <- nnet(stars~.,data=traindata,size=10, maxit=1000)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in nnet.default(x, y, w, ...) : too many (84581) weights
```

When I try changing weights in the argument like:

```
m4 <- nnet(stars~.,data=traindata,size=10, maxit=1000,weights=1000)
```

Then I get the following error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = stars ~ ., data = traindata, weights = 1000) : 
variable lengths differ (found for '(weights)')
```

What is the mistake I am making? How do I avoid or correct this error? Maybe the problem is with my understanding of "weights".

Answer (score 19):

Either increase `MaxNWts` to something that will accommodate the size of your model, or reduce `size` to make your model smaller.

You probably also want to think some more on exactly which variables to include in the model. Just looking at the data provided, `name` is a factor with more than 8000 levels; you're not going to get anything sensible out of it with only 10000 observations. `city` might be more useful, but again, 61 levels in something as complex as a neural net is likely to be marginal.

Comment: does "levels" refer to "values"?

Comment: @user1685185, a variable with ten "values" or "observations" might be: "B"; "B"; "A"; "A"; "C"; "B"; "C"; "A"; "B"; "C". This variable has ten values but only three levels ("A", "B", "C").

Answer (score 8):

Increase 'MaxNWts' option to something larger than 84581.

Comment: I have de same problem, and increasing MaxNWts does not solve the problem

Answer (score 3):

The option to set to increase the number of weights allowed in the network is `MaxNWts`, not `weights` (set to specify weights for each sample).

Answer (score 2):

Increase the MaxNWts parameter by passing it directly

```
m4 <- nnet(stars~.,data=traindata,size=10, maxit=1000,MaxNWts=84581)
```