# How to change weights in mlp general interface on tidymodels?

Tags: r, deep-learning, cross-validation, tidymodels

So I'm trying to fit a deep learning model into my data, using `tidymodels`. The general interface for this is `mlp()` and I'm using `fit_resamples()` in order to find the best model  to external data. I keep getting this error:

```
ann_model <-
  mlp(epochs = 50, hidden_units = 5, dropout = 0.1) %>%
  set_engine("nnet", weights = 10000) %>% 
  set_mode("regression")

ann_wflw <-
  workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(dados_recipe) %>% 
  add_model(ann_model)

ann_fit <- 
  ann_wflw %>% 
  fit_resamples(resamples = dados_cv)
```

---

```
x Fold01, Repeat1: model: Error in nnet.default(x, y, w, ...): too many (1301) weights

x Fold02, Repeat1: model: Error in nnet.default(x, y, w, ...): too many (1296) weights....
```

How do I change the weights? Please I'm really in a rush here.
BTW is there any other approach to not overfit my training data other than cross validation?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to increase `MaxNWts` parameter instead of `weights`.

I'm quoting the below from the answer at [I get error "Error in nnet.default(x, y, w, ...) : too many (77031) weights" while training neural networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105979/i-get-error-error-in-nnet-defaultx-y-w-too-many-77031-weights-whi)

> Either increase `MaxNWts` to something that will accommodate the size
> of your model, or reduce size to make your model smaller.

According to **nnet** documentation, `weights` is the

> (case) weights for each example – if missing defaults to 1

Whereas `MaxNWts` is

> The maximum allowable number of weights.  There is no intrinsic limit
> in the code,  but increasing MaxNWts will probably allow fits that are
> very slow and time-consuming

Comment: Thank you very much, that was pretty much the argument I was looking for!